# Prove the distributive law for maximum and minimum operation

Tags: binary-operations

Given $A=\{1,2,3,4\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and define the operation on $A$ as below

\begin{eqnarray}
a\oplus b&=& \max(a,b)\\
a\otimes b&=& \min(a,b)
\end{eqnarray}
for all $a,b\in A$.

Prove $(a\oplus b)\otimes c=(a\otimes b)\oplus(a\otimes c)$ for all $a,b,c\in A$.

I only can prove it with tables, but it spent long time. If I using tables, I must check $4^3=64$ possible way.

Now I try to prove with definition of operations as below.

\begin{eqnarray}
(a\oplus b)\otimes c&=&\max(a,b)\otimes c\\
&=&\min(\max(a,b),c)
\end{eqnarray}

Now I get stuck here. I cannot make this form
\begin{eqnarray}
(a\otimes b)\oplus(a\otimes c) &=& \min(a,b)\oplus \min(a,c)\\
&=& \max(\min(a,b),\min(a,c)).
\end{eqnarray}

Anyone can give me hint how to prove this distributive law for this operations?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to notice that with the association $n = \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ you have that $a\oplus b = a\cup b$ and $a\otimes b = a\cap b$. Then you can just use De Morgan's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stated the distributive law incorrectly. You want $$(a\oplus b)\otimes c=(a\otimes c)\oplus(b\otimes c)\quad(*)$$

The easiest approach is to look at 6 cases: $a>b>c,a>c>b,b>a>c,b>c>a,c>a>b,c>b>a$.

If you look at $a>b>c$, then $(a\oplus b)\otimes c=a\otimes c=c$. But $(a\otimes b)\oplus(a\otimes c)=b\oplus c=b$.

It is straightforward to verify $(*)$ for each of the six cases.

Comment: So, this operation is not distributive.